# Django Digitalocean Server won't update

Tags: django, webserver

I am working with DigitalOcean to run my django server for a client of mine but it appears as though my server has gotten 'stuck'. I was using the basic python library to send emails through django for testing purposes. Once I removed the code to send emails (because I was done with testing), my server refused to update. I've restarted gunicorn, nginx, and have done a full-on power cycle with digital ocean to no avail. What should I do? I can't find much online about how to resolve this issue, and I'm pulling my hair out on this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. Turns out that my FileZilla was not updating the changes back to the server, causing my changes not to be saved. Sorry for the inconvenience this may have caused anyone; I should have known to restart my computer before panicking.